# Online document editor - Where and what do I start with?

Tags: java, javascript, architecture, product

I plan to build a product that would let users do what Google Docs is doing today (although, not as good as Microsoft would do it) - edit word docs. The reason I can't use Google Docs is coz I need to build something new on top of it - like annotation support/ metadata support and all that.

So, if I were to start from scratch, How big a task is this going to be? Can I start with some  fancy JS libraries and extend them or something? For instance, something like yahoo pipes, non-flash, pure JS/HTML5 + ajax based web application. Are there open source alternatives that I can make use of?

Comment: Just so you know, this question isn't a good fit for SO - luckily it seems to have escaped closure, but it's way too broad, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs is an enormous and deceptively complicated application. It implements pretty much everything from scratch, including text selection, caret, text measurement and positioning and does easily the best job of this that I've seen in a browser. They've managed this, I assume, by having invested in an elite development team over a number of years.

All that being the case, trying to write something of the level of Google Docs is almost certainly a non-starter. You can get limited editing capabilities using `contenteditable` elements, but taming that particular beast is also an extremely tricky task and I'd recommend using one of the larger editors (CKEditor or TinyMCE, for example) at least as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I will see if these editors will work for me. Most likely they won't coz I want to open and edit existing docs - my understanding is that these editors don't let you edit word files as such.

Comment: @Jay: Indeed they don't, although I'm sure they'd do something with Word files saved as HTML.

Comment: Yea, I guess - that is the only option now. There is no real way to probably rendering a word doc close to what MS word does. The best option would be to convert doc to html and then edit that HTML in a editor like TinyMCE/CKEditor. What about using Canvas/SVG?

Answer (score 3):

Is it going to be pure JS editor(on the client side)? if so then.

1. Keep it modular(or try at least). Try **Sea.js** to separate stuff and load it on demand.
2. You need some editor to edit text of your doc: **TinyMCE, CKEditor, jWysiwyg** etc. (all of this uses iframes and contentEditable property to change page content on the fly).
3. Some proxy server to exchange information about docs(and keep info about docs too). Depending on the performance needed you can start off with **Apache and PHP and MySQL**(windows WAMP package).
   2.a For php server side you need some framework to get your logic together. Maybe **Symfony2, CakePHP** or other **MVC** frameworks(cool to use).
4. For real-time update you can use **Node.js** and **IOsocket(WebSockets)** to create peer to peer communication between users(one changes text, the other sees it immediately). **HTML5** browsers only tho.

The amount of work needed is depending on your requirements for this project. First of all create a specification, collect requirements, analyze the problem, implement, then test it.
4. For testing you can use some headless testing frameworks(still with node), jstestdriver etc.

That is what came to my mind first, Good luck.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your answer. I don't think TinyMCE/other editors that rely on frames will do it. What I am looking at is something that will actually read word specific formatting information from the server and display the same. The user should have the ability to edit such document. Pretty much like google doccs.

Comment: You dont have to have frames to make page editable. Just make document.contentEditable = true and it will behave somewhat like a doc.

Comment: Yep. What about loading an existing .docx file into browser? That won't be possible with TinyMCE/other editors?